# Increase field limit on elastic with C# NEST

Tags: elasticsearch, nest, elasticsearch-plugin

I'm getting an error with a bulk upload in elastic on C# - saying the field limit of 1000 is exceeded.

```
Limit of total fields [1000] in index
```

How can I increase the field limit with NEST in C#?

Comment: You have documetns with more than 1000 fields??

Comment: I have documents with a list/array field with > 1000 items.

Answer (score 1):

With the version 6.4 of ElasticSearch.net I do it in this way

```
var settings =  new { index = new { mapping = new  { total_fields = new { limit = 100000 } } } };

            List<object> listOfSettings = new List<object>() { settings };

var setResp = _es.IndicesPutSettings<StringResponse>({Your Index name here}, PostData.MultiJson(listOfSettings));
```

Answer (score 0):

You can update it by changing that index specific settings as shown below:

```
curl -XPUT '{elasticsearch_url}:9200/{index-name}/_settings' -d '
{
    "index.mapping.total_fields.limit": 3000
}'
```

Replace the above placeholders with your cluster information.

Comment: Is there a NEST/C# command or do I need to run a curl call via c#?

Comment: It should be done through NEST API also. Please check following link https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/net-api/1.x/update-settings.html

Answer (score 0):

Here is a version of [@MaurizioChionetti's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53007665/4751173) for ElasticSearch 7:

```
client.LowLevel.Indices.UpdateSettings<StringResponse>(
    indexNameResolver.Resolve(typeof(Product)),
    PostData.Serializable(new {
        index = new { mapping = new { total_fields = new { limit = 100000 } } }
    })
);
```

(here `client` is an `IElasticClient`)